# Having trouble with this stats question

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution

I have a question that asks to suppose that X and Y are two independent random variables both uniformly distributed on the unit interval [0,1].
I am asked to calculate the probability that

(a) $4X \leq Y^2 +2 $

(b) $4Y \leq Y^2 +2 $

(c) $2(X+Y) \leq Y^2 +2 $

I am not looking for the solution to this problem but would be thankful if somebody could help explain the right way to get started with these types of problems, because I am having difficulty with it.

Comment: The key to these problems involving two Uniform(0,1) random variables is that if you have a set of $(X,Y)$ values satisfying some relation and you want to know the associated probability, it is just the area of the region of points $(X,Y)$ that satisfy the relation. So for (a), what is the area of the region in the unit square satisfying $4X \le Y^2+2$?

Comment: what I considered doing so far is looking at what happens when $Y=0$ and when $Y=1$ this then gave me an area which I have calculated to be $\frac{1}{4}$ (I tired to find where $X = \frac{Y^2+2}{4}$) is this correct? or is there an alternative way that you would suggest?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to start out by plotting the boundary of the region of interest.  In (a), this would be the set of points satisfying $4X=Y^2+2$ for $X$ and $Y$ in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question.  This is not something that is easy to comprehend when you first encounter it.

These are all problems in conditional probability.

In (a) the sides of the inequality are independent, so you can just work out the density of $Z=Y^2+2$ and integrate it against the probability it will be greater than $4X$, which is just $z/4$ floored by zero and ceilinged by one.

In (b) the sides are completely dependent and this is really an algebra problem rather than a probability problem.  Then once you figure out the values of $Y$ that make it true, you can see the probability that a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ realizes those values.  (If the solution set is an interval, it's just the length of the intersection of that interval with $[0,1]$.)

In (c) the two sides are dependent but not totally dependent.  The easiest thing to do is to restate the inequality to have sides that are indepedent and then use the same method as for (a).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to do for (b), is this just a quadratic?

Comment: Sorry, I misstated the idea for (b).  Will go back to it in a minute.

Comment: It's all fixed now.

Comment: so for part (b) I am getting that $y=2+/-\sqrt{2}$ , how do I continue from here?

Comment: You get that (y-2)^2 needs to be bigger than or equal to 2.  Within [0,1], that only happens if $y\le 2-\sqrt{2}$.  So $2-\sqrt{2}$ is the probability that happens, since Y is uniform on [0,1].